# JQuery plugin is not working after ajax

Tags: jquery

I try to display a form on a bootstrap modal dialog and I would like to use a tooltip control on it as well. I am loading the content of the modal dialog using ajax load function.

I want to use the bootstrap tooltip control so I have to initalize when the content is loaded.

I catch the global ajax completed event and I put the tooltip initalizing code in this function.

```
 //Global Ajax Complete
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function (e, xhr, settings) {
    //Sent
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function (e, xhr, settings) {
    //Complete
    afterLoad();
}).bind("ajaxError", function (e, xhr, settings, thrownError) {
    //Error
});

function afterLoad() {
    // code to execute
    $(".btn").popover();

    $(".validator").tooltip();
}
```

My problem is when the content is loaded and the afterLoad function is executing I get the following error message:

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'popover'

The bootsrap js is included in the html I can use it any page but in the modal dialog page.

I guess because the content of the modal dialog is loading using ajax.

l.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you load jQuery more than once.  Don't do that!  When jQuery is loaded, it defines an object and assigns it to the name $.  When a plugin is loaded it modifies that object to add the new function(s) defined by the plugin.  When jQuery is loaded a second time, it (re)defines a new object and assigns it to the name $.  This second jQuery object doesn't have the data and additional functions that were stored in the first.